# Solving $\sinh x = kx$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

Can we solve the equation $\sinh x = kx$ for $x$ in terms of elementary functions? I've tried reexpressing the hyperbolic sine as exponentials and converting the equation into a quadratic in $e^x$, but this doesn't seem to make the problem any easier. I've considered expanding $\sinh x$ as a Taylor series, but this doesn't seem useful either.

Comment: $x=0$ is always a solution.

Comment: Also since the slope of $\sinh$ at zero is one and it is larger than one at any other point the only solution is zero for $k\le 1$. For $k>1$ there are three solutions that cannot be found in elementary terms.

Comment: No. It's even hard to solve with with the Lambert $W$ function, which sometimes can be used to solve similar problems.

Comment: All the above comments are easily seen by looking at the graph of $\sinh x$ and rotating a line around the origin.

Comment: Not all the comments - the fact that the equation can't be solved in elementary functions is impossible to see by looking at the graph.  @WhatsUp

Comment: @GReyes Actually, when $k>1$ then there are three solutions, one of which is $0$ and two others which cannot be represented in terms of elementary functions. (The two others are negatives of each other, so there is one positive solution.)

Comment: Sure, the trivial solution $x=0$ is an elementary function of $k$...

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments and answers, you will need a numerical method.

In any manner, instead of looking for the zero of
$$f(x)=\frac{\sinh (x)}{x}-k$$ it would be better to look for the zero of
$$g(x)=\log \left(\frac{\sinh (x)}{x}\right)-\log(k)$$ which is much more linear when $x$ is large.

Newton iterates would be
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n \sinh (x_n) \log \left(\frac{\sinh (x_n)}{x_n}\right)}{x_n \cosh (x_n)-\sinh (x_n)}$$

If $k$ is large and $x$ too, we could approximate
$$g(x)\sim\log \left(\frac{e^x}{2x}\right)-\log(k)\implies x\sim -W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 k}\right)$$ where appears the second branch of Lambert function (which is not elementary but simple to use).

Trying for $k=123.456789$, starting with the above estimate as $x_0$, Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 7.5276168997015533341 \\
 1 & 7.5276172335102603321 \\
 2 & 7.5276172335102591983
\end{array}
\right)$$

When $k$ is small, a very good approximation of $g(x)$ could be obtained using the $[4,4]$ Padé approximant of it. This will be
$$g(x)\sim \frac{21 x^2 \left(31 x^2+570\right)}{58 x^4+6300 x^2+71820}- \log(k)$$ which leads to a quadratic equation in $x^2$.

For $k=3$, the above gives $x=2.83971$ while the exact solution would be $x=2.83845$.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the only solution for $k\le1$ is $x=0$ and for $k>1$ there are 3 solutions: $x=0,\pm x_\star$. Although there is no closed form in terms of special functions such as the Lambert W function known, it is not hard to numerically compute $x_\star$, the positive nonzero solution. For example, we have [fixed-point iteration](https://tio.run/##bY67DoJAEEX7@Yqb0ABmUejhD6wsCQXoKmQ3CxHQMYZvx12D8RGnmce5c2fOY3WbPezkgKGWuJR6lGiPUPDI@xtECikSIm0ApCID474thzrS7cnnYCLJ3TewgyfoG1O/gG@HORfCJcFFsE4m2rf9L1998Llxf2WIyQpSaJMnoSoIhGvdaAnf@dsdCKiQg6iseqeWIt4Q0I1DD7bFezdkrLAcsD7SHJzZIrTdPD8A):

$$x_{n+1}=\ln(2kx_n+\exp(-x_n))$$

or [Newton's method](https://tio.run/##bY5NDoIwEIX3c4qXsKGYgrDHG7hySViAViE0QGzRGsPZa0vUqHE28/O9NzPnqb7ZADuhoRuBSyUngeGIDgEFf4OoQ46MSPYAcr6BwX1b6SaWwyk0bCZhxm/gBgtQbd@8QOiGhSm5T9yULMlm2g/ql68@uG39Xxuk5AQ5ZF9kUVcSCNemlQKh3@884Ogiw@KqVl4teLomYJy0gnGFAc/fWu6VSBD620vPCKI/@K1Ph@usfQA):

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\sinh(x_n)-kx_n}{\cosh(x_n)-k}$$

or any other numerical method.

Comment: A good starting point for such numerical methods is $1+\frac{x_0^2}{6}=k$ for $k$ only slightly larger than $1$. For $k\gg 1$, try $x_0=\ln(2k)$.

Comment: I would think it more beneficial to begin the Taylor expansion about $x=1$ for $k\approx1$ no?

Comment: If $\frac{\sinh x}{x}=k\approx1$, the fraction should be approximated as $1+\frac16x^2$.

Comment: But it'd be more accurate to use $kx=\sinh(x)\simeq\sinh(1)+\cosh(1)(x-1)$ (or another term if desired), since $x$ should be near $1$. Your point gives $x_0\approx0$, which will converge to the trivial solution instead.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I visualized the graph in my head wrong lol.

Comment: Has it been proven that there doesn't exist a closed form solution, or has it just been very difficult?

Comment: @NickA. The proof is a modification of the proof that the [Lambert W function is not elementary](https://mathoverflow.net/a/135922/91465).

Answer (score 1):

$0$ is one solution.

**1)**

$$\sinh(x)=kx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}e^x-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}=kx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(e^x)^2-\frac{1}{2}=kxe^x$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(e^x)^2-kxe^x-\frac{1}{2}=0\tag{1}$$

We see, equation (1) is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^x$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

We see, equation (1) is an irreducible algebraic equation of $x$ and $e^x$ simultaneously if $k$ is an algebraic number.
According to the theorems in [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999], such kind of equations cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or explicit elementary numbers respectively in this case. Therefore $x$ cannot be an elementary number except $0$ in this case and equation (1) cannot have partial inverses that are elementary functions over non-discrete domains.

We see, because equation (1) is a polynomial equation of $x$ and $e^x$ of a degree greater than $1$, the equation is not in a form for applying Lambert W, Generalized Lambert W or Hyper Lambert W.

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

**2)**

$$\sinh(x)=kx$$
$$\sinh(x)-kx=0$$
$x\to it$:
$$\sinh(it)-ikt=0$$
$$\sin(t)-kt=0$$
$$\frac{1}{k}\sin(t)-t=0$$
$$t-\frac{1}{k}\sin(t)=0$$

We see, this is Kepler's equation.

For $t\neq 0$, Kepler's equation can be solved by Hyper Lambert W:

$$t-\frac{1}{k}\sin(t)=0$$
$$t\ e^{\ln(1-\frac{1}{k}\frac{\sin(t)}{t})}=0$$
$$t=HW\left(\left\{\ln(1-\frac{1}{k}\frac{\sin(x)}{x})\right\}_1;0\right)$$

So we have a closed form for $t$, and the series representations of Hyper Lambert W give some hints for calculating $t$.

[[Galidakis 2005] Galidakis , I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

[[Dubinov/Galidakis 2007] Dubinov, A.; Galidakis, Y.: Explicit solution of the Kepler equation. Physics of Particles and Nuclei Letters 4 (2007) 213-216](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225894260_Explicit_solution_of_the_Kepler_equation)

[[Masson] Masson, Paul: Analytic Physics - An Exact Solution of the Complex Kepler Equation](https://analyticphysics.com/Special%20Functions/An%20Exact%20Solution%20of%20the%20Complex%20Kepler%20Equation.htm)