# Solving $R\space \sinh\frac{D}{R}=k$ for $R$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Does a solution exist for $R$ in this equation?  I can't seem to solve it either analytically or numerically.

$$R\space \sinh\frac{D}{R}=k$$

Comment: Is D a constant here?

Comment: It's a variable.  It's not something that needs to be solved, so, sure, constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$R\space \sinh\frac{D}{R}=k$$
$$\text{Let}\qquad x=\frac{D}{R}\qquad;\qquad R=\frac{D}{x}\qquad;\qquad C=\frac{k}{D}$$
$$\boxed{\sinh(x)=C\:x}$$
This equation is well known. For example see a discussion about the existence of root(s) in : [Solving $\sinh x = kx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472880/solving-sinh-x-kx)

The root cannot be expressed with a finite number of standard functions.

On a formal view-point (of no interest in practice) an analytical form of solution is :
$$R=\frac{D}{f^{-1}(k/D)}$$
where $f^{-1}$ is the inverse function of $f(x)=\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}$ . But this function $f^{-1}$ is not standard.

Of course, numerical solving is possible thanks to iterative methods for numerical solving of non-linear equations (For example Newton-Raphson method https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html).

Comment: Are you giving me an answer or proving that there isn't an analytical one?

Comment: The aim of my answer is not to prove something. I give you some information about the equations of the kind $\sinh(x)=C\:x$ .

Comment: Did you read https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472880/solving-sinh-x-kx . This clearly answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @JJacquelin's answer, you are looking for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\frac{\sinh(x)}x-C$$ The algebraic expression varies very fast which is never very good for numerical methods.

Consider instead looking for the zero of function (assuming $C>0$)
$$g(x)=\log \left(\frac{\sinh (x)}{x}\right)-\log(C)$$ which is much smoother and then better conditioned for the solver.

For sure, we need a starting point. A simple estimate could be
$$x_0=2.35 \big[\log(C)\big]^{3/4}$$  For testing, let me try for $C=123456789$. The iterates of Newton method will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 21.07424431 \\
 1 & 22.43727831 \\
 2 & 22.43517918 \\
 3 & 22.43517917
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you.  I've concluded as well that the problem can be solved numerically.  Mathematica made quick work out of the problem.  At this point, I'm looking for conclusive proof that it can't be solved analytically, which I guess we have.